# How to prevent bootstrap modal from closing when pressing ESC and not focused

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap modal to display details of some entries on my database. It includes text and image attachments.When I clicked on image attachment I show and focus a `div` to make a full screen view of that image.

What I want is when that image `div` is visible on the screen (doesn't contains "d-none" class) and I pressed `Esc` key, the `div` should close (Add "d-none" class). I was able to do it by adding `keydown` event on that `div`. However, the modal automatically closes as well together with the image `div` when I'm pressing the `Esc` key. How should I prevent that?

I don't want to permanently disable the "Closing on Esc key" feature of the modal I just want to disable it when the image `div` is visible on the screen.

NOTE: If it includes script please give vanilla js solution.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question, adding `e.stopPropagation()` inside the keydown event of image `div` worked for me.

I also added `tabindex="0"` to the image div and set focus when displaying the image div using `document.getElementById('#image-div').focus()`.

Hope it will be a help.